# How can I see if a Groupmanaged Service Account is installed with Install-ADServiceaccount?

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2014

actually I'm testing with Microsofts Groupmanaged Service Accounts on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I'm curious to know, if there is a way to see whether such an account has been installed with the `Install-ADServiceaccount` Commandlet on a computer or not. So what have I done sofar?

1. I have created a global security group in my AD

   ```
   New-ADGroup -name SQLServers -GroupScope Global -GroupCategory Security
   ```
2. I have added the relevant computeraccount to the SQLServers group

   ```
   Add-ADGroupMember -identity SQLServers -Members MSSQLSERVER
   ```
3. I have created a fresh gMSA

   ```
   New-ADServiceAccount -Name MSSQLSERVER -DNSHostname mydnsserver.mydomain.de 
   -PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPasswort SQLServers -Enabled $true
   ```
4. I have used Install-ADServiceAccount on my SQL Server Machine to install the MSSQLSERVER gMSA

   ```
   Install-ADServiceAccount -Identity MSSQLSERVER
   ```

Back to my question. Is it possible to see, whether or not the Install-ADServiceAccount Commandlet has been successfully executed on a computer? Let's say I want to check this on a server that I did not install all by myself. Is there a way with Powershell?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Get-ADServiceAccount? [Syntax here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617204.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `Get-ADServiceAccount` is not able to prove, that `Install-ADServiceAccount` has been executed for a MSA. I only tells me that the account exists and it shows me its properties.

Comment: You can use the filter option to find out the MSA installed on the remote server or not : `Get-ADServiceAccount -Filter {HostComputers -eq "CN=Server64, DC=SS64,DC=com" }` [ss64](http://ss64.com/ps/get-adserviceaccount.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!