# Obtaining list of servers where a Group Managed Service Account is installed

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a whole bunch of GMSA used throughout my org. I'm able to see through AD what machines have permissions to install the GMSA but cannot find a way to see what machines have actually gone through the `Install-ADServiceAccount` step to actually have the GMSA installed.

An older post [How can I see if a Groupmanaged Service Account is installed with Install-ADServiceaccount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841372/how-can-i-see-if-a-groupmanaged-service-account-is-installed-with-install-adserv) suggests using`Get-ADServiceAccount` and checking the HostComputers property but I only see this populated for MSA. For GMSA it's blank.

Any ideas on how I can get this without needing to connect to each machine and running `Test-ADServiceAccount` for each permitted GMSA? (especially given the whole PSRemoting and network access that causes problems) A WMI/CIM query I could run would be second to actually getting the data centrally from AD.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, gMSA should be tested locally so you would need to have permissions to invoke command remotely on each computer that is a member of a gMSA group.

Comment: Testing locally is something I've been doing to this point, but that does not scale well. That there's no attribute anywhere to see what accounts are installed or what servers an account is installed on seems to be an unexpected failure in tooling.

Comment: There should be, each gMSA account should have the attribute `PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword` which generally points to a Security Group which (the group) should have AD `computer objects` added as members.

Comment: Those are machines with the relevant access, however, it does not, unfortunately, have any bearing on what machines the gmsa is installed on.

Comment: Oh yeah, I agree, but from that point supposing you had permissions to invoke commands to those remote hosts you could _in theory_ test the gMSA account on each remote host (_untested_).

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but `Install-ADServiceAccount` caches a gmsa on a local computer and not install it as it is done with a MSA. So, despite an old habit (I do it too), this is not mandatory to use it for a gMSA (see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/install-adserviceaccount?view=windowsserver2022-ps)). `PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword` is the only way. You can retrieve computers that are really using the gMSA by checking the profile folder of these computers. If the gMSA is **OR** was used , there will be a directory for it.